# How to get the Bearer Token in my REST controller

Tags: c#, graph, bearer-token

Hello (sorry for my bad english)

I have an Angular Vue.js front that connect to my Rest Api Services in C# . I have at least 20 services developed. Now I want to secure them.

With POSTMAN and the url https://login.microsoftonline.com... I get the "Token" , then I try to get the authorization and I put hardCode the given token , and the result its:
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ReasonPhrase": "Authorized",

I do something like this:

```
    public class TokenController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> d = TokenManager.GetGroups("token");
            return Ok(d);
        }
    }


    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetGroups(string token)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups";
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        var res = httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;

        return Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(t => res);
    }
```

My problem its that I don´t know where or what I have to do to Get the "Bearer Token" from the "Front". I can't get the token by parameter in the URL of the service because is to long.

Thank you.

Comment: Using `.Result` will cause you deadlock headaches down the line. Teach yourself how to use TAP properly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: I try using this:  
  using (var res2 = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead))
                {
                    string json = await res2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    userInformation = parser.Deserialize<EntityGraphUser>(json);
                    userInformation.StatusCode = res2.StatusCode.ToString();
                    userInformation.ReasonPhrase = res2.ReasonPhrase;
                }
but I don't get any answer.. postman stay loading...    I google more .. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With Request.Headers I have the Bearer Token.

I call  "string tt = Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString();" in my controller and it works fine